# Blender scripting connect nodes

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

I'am beginner at python and blender. I' am trying to create simple addon for myself as part of learning process. I want to achieve that, if i run the script, mixrgb node is added to node tree and link to shader, and if i run script again another mixrgb node is added and linked to shader instead of previous one and previous one link to new one input. Here is the code

```
import bpy
nodes = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes
links = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.links
mix = nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixRGB')


mix.location = (-300, -200)
mix.label = "mix"

for n in nodes :
    if n.label == "mix" :
    n.location.y -= 200
links.new(mix.outputs[0], nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs[0])
```

Node is created and linked to shader, if i run the script again , new node is created and conected to shader ,previous one change its y location , and here i would like to link old node output to new node input.

I tried

```
links.new(mix.outputs[0] , mix.inputs[1])
```

But it conects to itself.
I dont want to make separate nodes like mixrgb2 mixrgb3, because i would like to be able to add infinite number of nodes , which are linked to previous.

If somebody can show me the correct way or creating that, iam stuck in that point for few days already. I was searching for solution here and every other forum, but no success, that 's why i decided to make a post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Look for the link.**

[image]
*Each run of script, offsetting old mix node
's `location.x`*

- Put all current mix nodes into a list.
- Find any links between a mix node and the principle shader
- Make a new mix node.
- If there's a link attach the from node (a mix node) output to the
  input of new mix node
- Make link new mix node to principled shader
- Move the old mix nodes.  Could do this prior... sometimes handy to post-process incase a prior step is aborted.)

Test script

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
nodes = context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes
links = context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.links
ps = nodes.get('Principled BSDF')


mixnodes = [n for n in nodes if n.label == "mix"]
mix_ps_links = [l for l in links if l.from_node.label == "mix" and l.to_node == ps]

# add new mix node
mix = nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixRGB')
mix.location = (-300, -200)
mix.label = "mix"

if mix_ps_links:
    link = mix_ps_links.pop()
    links.new(link.from_node.outputs[0], mix.inputs[0])

links.new(mix.outputs[0], ps.inputs[0])

for mix in mixnodes:
    mix.location.y -= 200
```

Note: I use the line in test code `context = bpy.context` to make it cut and paste directly into methods where `context` is passed, eg `def execute(self, context):`

Comment: That was very fast and good answer. Your solution is perfect for my little project, i managed to make all of the linking and creating nodes. Still have a lot to learn and a lot of questions.

Comment: well done batFinger!!! But...i wanna complain ...your code does not fit to your animation. In reality the mixnodes are arranged under each other, not to the left side ;) ...sorry, could not resist. Of course you got an upvote from me!

Comment: and i have a little "improvement" ;) hope you don't mind: mix.location = (ps.location.x - ps.width - 100, ps.location.y).  would give a better positioning, independent from the "real" location of the bsdf ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the previously created node and pass it on to the next iteration of the loop. See the sample code below:

```
import bpy
nodes = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes
links = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.links
principled = nodes.get('Principled BSDF')

number_of_mix_nodes = 5
previous_mix = None

for n in range(number_of_mix_nodes):
    mix = nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixRGB')
    mix.location = ((number_of_mix_nodes - n) * -300 + principled.location.x, principled.location.y)
    mix.label = f"mix_number_{n}"

    if previous_mix:
        # only if previous_mix is not None, try to connect it
        # to the new mix node
        links.new(previous_mix.outputs[0], mix.inputs[0])

    # let previous_mix point to this mix, so it will be connected
    # the next time the loop is executed
    previous_mix = mix

links.new(mix.outputs[0], principled.inputs[0])
```

Aside from arranging the nodes relative to the current location of the Principled node, the key here is to introduce the `previous_mix` variable. In the beginning it is set to `None`, so the `if previous_mix` statement will be skipped. Right after that, I re-hook `previous_mix` to `mix`. Next time the loop is run, `previous_mix` contains the first created node, and a second (new) mix node is created. This game can be repeated as many times as you want, just change the `number_of_mix_nodes` variable.