# simple python script to add nodes

Tags: python, node-editor

I almost have no clue regarding python and scripting, and I was wondering if there is a simple script to create two nodes in the shader editor.

Something like this:

[image: uv map to image texture shader editor]

UV map → Image texture

That's it. but every time I try to copy from the info window I get errors in the console, please help!

Comment: [Node types](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNode.html) in your case: `ShaderNodeUVMap` and `ShaderNodeTexImage`

Comment: @brockmann Hi, I understand that I need to use node types but as I said I am a complete noob and I just can't understand how to call the nodes and how to connect them. i have seen this post   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145882/blender-scripting-connect-nodes  but still when i try to connect other nodes rather than the principled bsdf i get an error and unable to connect

Comment: you can where i got to at: https://ctxt.io/2/AABAG2QCFA

Comment: All pretty well explained in the dupe (no need for that other post). Take your time and try to understand it. To get the ball rolling: https://pastebin.com/VWMwGhmP

Comment: Okay, thanks you

Comment: Hi @brockmann, could you please help me with this? I am trying to create an operator button to lunch the script (i have amended it a bit to suit my needs better)  but i keep getting an 'invalid bl_idname' error,  i was looking all over and trying to figure it out but no luck :/  pls help: https://pastebin.com/T4eyauft

Comment: You need an execute method as already explained to you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167870/31447 (Try to understand: **2 Operator**). Also change `bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name` to `context.active_object.active_material.name`.

Comment: @brockmann okay thank will look into it

Comment: @brockmann LOWER CASE?! I was ripping my hair out! haha :)
(class OBJECT_OT_fancy_tool (and bl_idname = "object.fancy_tool")
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons#Naming

Comment: thanks for the lesson, now i need  to create a check for materials otherwise it raises an error, thanks again hope it wont be too complicated

Comment: See my answer again on the the poll method (**2 Operator**). Add a `poll(cls, context)` and return `context.object.active_material is not None`, done. (will grey out the button)

Comment: @brockmann Sorted! :) thanks for all your help, I really like automating things in blender for my workflow, helps a lot.. I guess I will learn, slowly.. 
https://pastebin.com/dRfj1wKQ

Comment: Looks good. Suggest to add `bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}` to the operator (makes it possible to undo its execution).... Further reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui

Comment: @brockmann ok, great idea! Thanks 