# Connecting A Node Group Between Principled and Output Shaders With Python

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, add-on, development

I am aware I could do

```
material_output = bpy.data.materials[bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name].node_tree.nodes.get('Material Output')
    material_output.location = (600,400)
    principled_node = bpy.data.materials[bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name].node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')
    principled_node.location = (100,400)

    link = bpy.data.materials[bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name].node_tree.links.new

    link(principled_node.outputs[0], dust_node.inputs[0])
    link(dust_node.outputs[0], material_output.inputs[0])
```

But I want the node group to connect between the shader output and the main output, regardless of what the final shader is - Whether it be mix or principled, I just want it to connect between that last connection.

Is this possible?

Comment: `material_output = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.get('Material Output')`

Comment: That is exactly the same as what I put in my question?

Comment: Yes both `bpy.data.materials[bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name]`  and  `bpy.context.active_object.active_material` (if they exist) are references to same material.  Totally unnecessary to use  name from one reference to reference  samel from materials collection. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145882/blender-scripting-connect-nodes

Comment: Ok but that wasn't the question,