# Connecting node trees using blender api

Tags: scripting

I am terribly confused why this is not working. I have followed similar examples and failed (i.e. [Blender scripting connect nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145882/blender-scripting-connect-nodes))

`bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.links.new(bpy.data.materials["Material.001"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0], bpy.data.materials["Material.001"].node_tree.nodes["ShaderNodeTexCoord"].outputs[0])`

If my code is too difficult to decipher, here's a summary: I am just trying to link the Texture Coordinate node output to the Base Color input of the Principled BSDF.

I wrote out the whole line above without using any variables in the aid of clarity/searchability.

Thank you all!

Comment: Your last part includes `.from_node.` which is not correct offhand.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried without as well. Same result. I will edit the question above for clarity.

Comment: did you select an object when running your script?

Comment: what is the error of python?

Comment: Re clarity and search ability, not convinced it has have achieved either.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your name is set to right value, not just the label.

"[image]

Comment: If the active objects active material is not material "Material.001" then code in question won't work... could be another guess-timate.

Comment: Nobody with little python experience would code it in that way - so I totally agree with you